# How to customize 'WordPress' in sent email using wp_mail function?

Tags: email

I am creating a contact form on WordPress site.

The form is perfectly working with following code:

`//validate email
      if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
      else //email is valid
      {
        //validate presence of name and message
        if(empty($name) || empty($topic) || empty($message)){
          my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
        }
        else //ready to go!
        {
          $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
          if($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent); //message sent!
          else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent); //message wasn't sent
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else if ($_POST['submitted']) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
?>`

However, this sends email with 'From' name as 'WordPress'.

I want to customize 'WordPress' with sender name for which I am using $name variable, so that I got to know who send me email without opening it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$to = 'emailsendto@example.com';
$name= 'jhon';
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('From: '.$name.'');

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

I hope it'll work as you want.

Comment: Thanks, please share me, where to add this code in the snippet I shared in original post.

Comment: This doesn't works. I replaced it with this code:

$to = get_option('admin_email');
  $subject = "[Contact Form] ".$name;
  $headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to change this for ALL outbound mail generated by your site is a plugin called [CB Change Mail Sender](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cb-change-mail-sender/).  I have used it a lot. Performance is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't want to additional plugins.